# Keeping PHP session alive during file upload/download

Tags: php

I have a PHP project that transfers large files between the client and server. There are a couple of things I'm wondering about. The first is how do I ensure that the session stays alive, even if the client has a slow internet connection and the upload takes longer than the usual session timeout allows? And then how do I also make sure that if the client gets disconnected or something, that the session dies as expected? Is there any straightforward way to test this, other than transferring a large file, hoping that it takes longer than the usual timeout and then testing `isset($_SESSION['var'])`? Thanks.

Comment: use an ajax request every x interval.

Answer (score 0):

When you start upload you need to start also ajax calls to end point on your server that will refresh session with interval a few minutes shorter than your session timeout. That will refresh the session. When upload has an error or complete you need to stop ajax calls. For upload you can use YUI or any other lib that provides API to monitor upload's progress/errors.